# i need a customised Range Slider as attached

Tags: angular, angular-material, node-modules

I have a Figma design which needs a customized range slider.
attaching the Figma design here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is: Where you can get this?

PrimeNG has this:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/slider

When you adjust the CSS a little, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ngx-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-slider/ngx-slider) to achieve your UI; angular-material won't give you that OOTB.